# Can't install anything because of JDK9 unsuccessful installation

Tags: jdk

**Note**: The JDK9, I tried to install is a 9 Early Access Release version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java /* added repository */
sudo apt-get update /* updated */
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer /* I can't instal JDK 9 */
```

Note: I have installed JDK 8 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. 
[image]

When I do `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer` I get the error shown in below picture.
[image]

When I do `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing`, I get uses weka digest algorithm (SHA1) warnings for some gpg keys as shown below.
[image]

I can't do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or **any software installation**, I get error because of JDK 9 installation incompete.

I removed `oracle-java9` related ppa sources file from /`etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and also removed `oracle-jdk9-installer` folder from `/etc/apt` and removed `oracle-java9` related packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

I have not selected any java related ppa sources in my `sources.list` file.
[image]

Every time I try to install/remove/configure something, I get error of JKD9 aso shown below. And the folder `oracle-jdk9-installer` that I removed in the past from /var/cache again appears.

**Because of this incomplete installation of JDK9, I can't install/remove/configure anything in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.**

I searched how apt-get works in [What does apt-get install do under the hood?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540937/what-does-apt-get-install-do-under-the-hood), nothing found because there is no single file inside `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory. There is nothing related to java or oracle things in the `/var/lib/dpkg/list` directory as well.

After researching sometime in the internet, I found that I can install JDK9 using `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install openjdk-9-jdk`. I ran this script, but still I get the error as presented below picture.
[image]

I checked there is nothing in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file. **I wanna know, from where apt-get is reading the configuration information? So that I can remove all java9 reated information from that file and solve my problem**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
```

solved my issue. 
Later I also changed Ubuntu Software center server to "Main Server".