# Will lubuntu 17.10 work as a server?

Tags: server, lubuntu, xampp

after checking on google for the light weight linux distro, I just started using Lubuntu 17.10. I was thinking, in windows there's a service IIS to make it work like a server in local network. Does Lubuntu have something like that? Does Lubuntu work like server by default or do I have to enable something. By installing 3rd party software like xampp/lamp it may work but do I have to install it really? TIA

Comment: Not by default, You'll need to install the various components of XAMPP or LAMP, but be sure to do it using `apt install` rather than installing from source code with `make` and so on. This will ensure you can easily get security updates with a simple `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Yes I use `apt-get install` and I feel great about it. How does it work really? It's amazing...

Comment: It installs the basic files for a piece of software like, for example, Apache. Then, `apt upgrade` can easily replace the files with new versions. For more details, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/540937/616451).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any GNU/Linux distribution as a server but you will need to install couple of packages. The latter are not 3rd party in debian-based distributions, including Ubuntu, since they are part of official repositories. Indeed, it is better to have a light distribution. General rules recommend to not use graphical environment for a server. [Ubuntu provides a much lighter version dedicate for servers](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)
During the installation, you will be prompt to choose which kind of server you want to install, it is call [Tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel). You can also install the packages after the installation.
If you stick to Lubuntu, you will need to install the packages after the installation.
After the installation, in a terminal, you can either use Taskel, e.g. for a LAMP server

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

or APT

```
sudo apt install apache2 php mysql-server libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Didn't know about `tasksel`, like to try it. Does Lubuntu come with LAMP by default?

Comment: No, you will need to launch either command I wrote above after the installation (and that's all you need!). But it is pretty straight forward, you write one of them, enter, wait couple of minutes, and you have your LAMP running, and you can check at http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/

Comment: @Kaysar, consider accepting my reply if you think it answer your questions.

Comment: cool! thanks... I'm working with xampp though..