# How to create an offline script with zip file to be run instead of running an apt-get install command?

Tags: apt, software-installation, offline, kerberos

I'm helping someone to install a [Kerberos Linux Client](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-kerberos) on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server which is currently offline from the internet. This will be later used to setup authentication to connect to a Kakfa service.

If it was online, this simple `apt-get` command would be enough:

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-user krb5-config libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
```

I though about zipping the `krb5-config krb5-user libgssrpc4 libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-8 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit` downloaded files (as seen on my server* log) and give him the instruction to where to put them. This may or [may not be enough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540937/what-does-apt-get-install-do-under-the-hood).

What should I do, then?

*obs: the offline server is a similar version of my online server.

Comment: cant you go to a place like https://pkgs.org/download/ and search the packages to download the deb files then you can just install deb files for those items you want .. I checked .. they have krb5-user krb5-config libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit available

Comment: @JohnOrion the given link returns 404 error; thanks for giving me this idea

Comment: oh that's just a link to get to the site .. you need to type the file names in the search at the top of the page to find the download pages in that site... but probably any repo will have the files too

Comment: Yeah, I also see that the search settings let me select the OS version and architecture! About _install deb files for those items_ could you also suggest a good link? Thanks!

Comment: not really sure what you are asking here... do you mean is there a site on how to install deb files?

Comment: I apologize, I have never dealt with .deb files. I meant to ask for a link with instructions on how and where to install them

Comment: ahh ok .. heres one I found that is pretty clear :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt