# How to correct dpkg

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

I have a problem with dpkg. When I try to install software it gives error code

```
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Output of `ls -la /usr/bin/dpkg`:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/dpkg: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the output from `ls -la /usr/bin/dpkg`. Could be a permission problem there.

Comment: This is the result. ls: cannot access /usr/bin/dpkg: No such file or directory
  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted your dpkg and need to reinstall it.

Get dpkg eiter from the liveCD or [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/).
Make sure you select the correct version for your distro.

Since you don't have dpkg installed anymore you cannot use it to install the .deb file.
You have to use `ar` to unpack the .deb archive. (Use `man ar` for details).

Then copy dpkg in `/usr/bin/`, and use `chmod 750 /usr/bin/dpkg` to set the right permissions for the executable.

Comment: Relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110988/how-do-i-install-packages-without-using-a-package-manager

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved problem using your method thank you again.