# dpkg returns to error code one

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

I had a proble with dpkg before and I corrected it using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544095/how-to-correct-dpkg/544110#544110). After correcting that issue everything was good. But now dpkg has another problem

```
sudo apt-get install xix-media-playe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xix-media-player is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-menus.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-menus.
nst: dpkg-maintscript-helper: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Setting up xix-media-player (0.35-a~trusty~Noobslab.com) ...
mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/xixplayer/x32/xix-music-player’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package xix-media-player (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
gnome-menus
xix-media-player
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know reason for this crap. Please help me to correct this problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, i had the same problem... Just follow these steps and you will be out of that mess

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/xix-media-player.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq xix-media-player
sudo apt-get remove xix-media-player
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Can you explain what these commands do and why they are necessary?